# Design classes in C#

Tags: c#, class, oop, associations, object-relationships

Recently I had attended an interview and was given this question:

**Question:** ***With the following entities with you, design a class diagram or skeleton code:***

The entities are:

**`garment` `shirt` `pant` `fabric` `buttons` `zip`**

```
The best I could do was this:


class Shirt : Fabric 
{
  Buttons buttons {get;set;}
  //Inherits all Fabric methods

  MakeShirt()  
  {
    //make a shirt here
  }
}

class Pant : Fabric
{
  Buttons buttons {get;set;}
  // Inherits all Fabric methods

  MakePant()
  {
     //Make a pant here
  }
}


class Fabric
{
  private MaterialType materialType {get;set;}
  private FabricType fabricType {get;set;}

  Fabric(MaterialType mType, FabricType fType)
  {
     this.materialType = mtype;
     this.fabricType = fType;
  }

  public GetFabricMaterial();
  public GetFabricType();

}

class Garment : IGarment
{
  Price price {get;set;}
  Audience audience {get;set;}
}

enum FabricType
{
  Fabric_Formal,
  Fabric_Casual,
}

enum MaterialType
{
   Fabric_Cotton,
   Fabric_Silk,
   Fabric_Wool, 
}

class Buttons
{
Color color {get;set;}
Shape shape {get;set;}
}

class Zip
{
Color color {get;set;}
Size size {get;set;}
}
```

But still I can see many things missing out from the above skeleton code.

1. How can I relate `Garment` with the other entities (Object relationship! ?)
2. What can be the return type of functions `MakeShirt()` and `MakePant()` ?
3. While answering these questions, what approach is best ? In other words, how to approach these type of questions ?

Any inputs on this is appreciated. *(If this is not the right question to be asked here, kindly let me know to move this to the right stackoverflow site!)*

Comment: Hmm. Is a shirt a fabric? I'd venture that it's a garment, and that the garment *has* a fabric.

Comment: Shirt,pant are garments.Garment is made from fabric.

Comment: @spender: Assuming that shirt is a fabric, can you kindly point me how to modify my classes please ?

Comment: Shirts and pants are garments. A garment is made of (has) different fabrics. Also - in my opinion - a garment can have zips and buttons. (But it may be that pants have zip and shirts have buttons, in that case those are accessories (or something like that), and a garment can have those).

Comment: Pants and shirt would inherit from garment. Fabric should be an interface, since garments are made of fabric (have it's properties) but are not fabric themselves. You would use composition for zip and buttons, since they are not common to all garments. Pants have a zip property, shirt has a buttons property.

Comment: Also pants don't make themselves.... That would be a method of a PantsFactory which seems beyond the scope of your exercise.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin: Yup, correct! Thanks for the pointers

Comment: I forgot that pants do also have buttons, but anyway sounds like you get the point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you over thought this, I see it as this.  Pants and Shirts are `Garment`. Garments are made up of Fabric.

Pants have Zip, shirts have buttons..

```
public enum Fabric { Cotton, Silk, Poly }

public abstract Garment{


    public Fabric Fabric {get; set; }
}

class Buttons
{
  Color color {get;set;}
  Shape shape {get;set;}
}
class Zip
{
   Color color {get;set;}
   Size size {get;set;}
}

public class Shirt : Garment{
   public Buttons Buttons { get; set;} 
}
public class Pants : Garment{
  public Zip Zip { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Okay.Great, and about that `object-relationships` part? any inputs please?

Comment: I'm wearing Pants with buttons today ;)

Comment: @TMcKeown: Sure, I will research from this point and figure out that :)  Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Jeb: I am making that `Button` null ;)

Comment: `Pants have Zip, shirts have buttons..` -> Does this mean, i should move the `zip`, `buttons` to `Garment` class, and the inheriting classes `Shirt` and `Pant` could use appropriate items and make others null ? Eg: `Shirt` can assign `null` to `zips`.

Comment: I think that is an unnecessary constraint. I would move the zip and buttons properties to the garment class (as I mentioned in my answer) in order for you to have more flexibility for shirts/pants. Yes, just make it return null if it doesn't exist. You can even add something like a HasZip and HasButtons methods on the Garment class (which just return _zip != null) so you can ask

Answer (score 1):

This is more an exercise in parent/child relationships. I would have thought `Garment` is your abstract base class from which `Shirt` and `Pant` inherit. `Fabric`, `Buttons` and `Zip` are all *properties* of a `Garment`.

I wouldn't have specific Make methods. The constructor for the specific Garment types should make the Garment type ready to go instead of post initialising it.